# webpack is building a lots of files instead of one

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, web-deployment

When building my app with webpack to the `./dist` folder, I get a lot of file whereas I'm expecting to have only one. My `./dist` folder looks like:

```
657.main.js
657.main.js.LICENSE.txt
657.main.js.map
726.main.js
main.js
main.js.LICENSE.txt
main.js.map
```

When I'm expecting:

```
main.js
```

My webpack config is the following:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry:  './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'foobar',
  }
}
```

When removing all other files except `main.js` I get errors.

Is there a way to build my app to only one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack by default is chucking/code splitting the modules. You can disable/set max number of chunks it by using this plugin:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/

Comment: Is there  advantages of code splitting the modules that I will loose if I use the plugin?